# LIMITING MAX VALUES IN SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, db2, max, limit

I am completely rewriting this question, I just cant crack it

IDB DB2 SQL

(from a Chicago Crime Dataset)
Which community area is most crome prone?

When I use this code, it does correctly count and sort the data

```
select community_area_number as community_area_number, count(community_area_number) as total_area_crime
from chicago_crime_data
group by community_area_number
order by total_area_crime desc;
```

the problem is, it lists *all* the data descending, but no matter what MAX statement I use, either in the select or the order by statement, it wont show just the max values.
The max values are 43, so I would like to to show both 'community_area_numbers' that have 43.

Instead it shows the entire list.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

also, yes I understand I can just do a LIMIT 2 command, but that would be cheating since I manually checked that there are 2 max values, but if this data changed or i didnt know that, it doesnt solve anything

thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what sql engine/db you are using but this sounds like a RANK query, not MAX

Comment: tag with database platform

Comment: sorry about that guys, ill update it with the platform, i have updated it above, it is IDB DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would be looking for is the standard SQL clause `FETCH WITH TIES`;

```
select community_area_number, count(*) as total_area_crime
from chicago_crime_data
group by community_area_number
order by total_area_crime desc
fetch first row with ties;
```

Unfortunately, though, DB2 doesn't support `WITH TIES` in `FETCH FIRST`.

The classic way (that is before we had the window functions `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`) is to use a subquery: Get the maximum value, then get all rows with that maximum. I am using a CTE (aka `WITH` clause) here in order not to have to write everything twice.

```
with counted as
(
  select community_area_number, count(*) as total_area_crime
  from chicago_crime_data
  group by community_area_number
)
select community_area_number, total_area_crime
from counted
where total_area_crime = (select max(total_area_crime) from counted);
```

(Please note that this is a mere `COUNT(*)`, because we want to count *rows* per community_area_number.)

Comment: thanks a lot! I already did it another way, as described below, but this is the *proper* way! im surprised I never thought of something so simple as just ceperating the sub queries into 1 larger one!

Answer (score 1):

Like @topsail mentioned. You could use a [rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

From the table you have above you could do the following

```
SELECT t.* FROM
   (
    SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER (Order by Total_Area_Crime DESC) rnk
    from 
    table1
    )t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4362b5b43994313f43116dd19cd5c716)

So your full query should look something like this:

```
With cte AS (
    SELECT MAX(COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) AS COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, 
    COUNT(COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) AS TOTAL_AREA_CRIME
    FROM CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA 
    GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
    ORDER BY TOTAL_AREA_CRIME DESC;
)
SELECT t.* FROM
   (
    SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER (Order by Total_Area_Crime DESC) rnk
    from 
    cte
    )t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw that on another SO question as well, but we technically havent learned the RANK function yet, so that would be cheating lol. I wish there was a way I could go back but there isnt even an example in the curriculum for this question, which makes me think i might just be overcomplicating it, and it would have a super easy solution.

One way is to put LIMIT 2 but that just feels like cheating, since I would have to know there are 2 top results, which in a real world situation would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the professor *did* want us to use the Limit command.
Here is the final answer:

```
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, COUNT(ID) AS CRIMES_RECORDED 
FROM CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA
GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER 
ORDER BY CRIMES_RECORDED DESC LIMIT 1;
```

thanks to all those who responded :D

Comment: So, the professor made a mistake. It is very important to think about ties whenever dealing with a top n problem.